# SelectedItem is updating when ListCollectionView changes

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listcollectionview

I am using WPF, MVVM, and entity framework.

I am working with a data entry application, and I am trying to enable cancel changes to work in my app.  Where when changes are cancelled, all values reset to their original value.  I think I have everything on the EF side setup correctly.  Basically I just set all entities to unchanged if they are in the modified list.

My problem is when I come back to the ViewModel, and I am trying to re-setup all of the fields and derived properties.  The biggest annoyance has been the collections.  We have multiple combo box controls that we bind to a ListCollectionView and then I have an additional property in the view model that represents the SelectedItem.  When I am resetting up the collections I was just allowing the process to re-initiate all the properties including the collections.  When I change the collection, it tries to also change the selected property.  The problem with this is if it changes the selected property the backing entity gets updated with the new values (as if the user selected an item), and I technically can't get the value back.

I was actually having a reverse problem when I was saving.  After the save the form would go into its not edit mode and the value would be set to the old value.  Re-opening the form in edit would load the correct value.  To fix this I added to the form IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true.  But now I am having the problem reverse problem where the value goes back to old value during edit.

```
// View Code
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="2" 
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TransformerTypeDisplayDataTemplate}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TransformerTypeCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTransformerType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  Style="{StaticResource AssetViewStateAwareComboBox}" Margin="0,0,0,2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

//ViewModel Properties
private ListCollectionView<TransformerType> _transformerTypeCollection;
public ListCollectionView<TransformerType> TransformerTypeCollection
{
    get { return _transformerTypeCollection; }
    set { _transformerTypeCollection = value; RaisePropertyChanged("TransformerTypeCollection"); }
}
private TransformerType _selectedTransformerType;
public TransformerType SelectedTransformerType
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedTransformerType;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedTransformerType = value;
        if (IsInEditMode)
        {
            BackingEntity.TransformerTypeID = _selectedTransformerType.ID;
            BackingEntity.TransformerType = _selectedTransformerType;
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTransformerType");
    }
}

// Setting the collection will trigger the set method for SelectedTransformerType
TransformerTypeCollection = TaskCoordinator.TransformerTypes.GetView();
```

My current work around for this problem is I keep around a state variable that says the collections have already been populated.  And it skips the resetting the collections on the re-setup of the view model.

Comment: Could you post some code snippets of what you have so far?

Comment: Edited: Added some code samples

Comment: Why does changing the collection change the selecteditem, is that the intended functionality? if you essentially want to unselect you can set the item to null or selectedindex to -1 and then just have your setter not write to the backingentity if that is the value

Comment: That is my question.  I don't want changing the collection to change the selected item, but it does.  This code was not originally mine and was created when my team didn't fully understand MVVM practices.  It is very possible that there is something in our code that updates all properties when the collection changes.  Are you saying it should not auto update selected item if you change the collection?

Comment: If you are changing the avaiable options it makes sense to clear the selecteditem. In this case check in the setter that the value isn't null empty before writing to backing entity. If it defaults to the first element in the list when changing the list, then that might be trickier

Comment: It is actually defaulting to the last value i chose before the cancel.  We have one class that is doing weird stuff related to actually putting the one you choose into the first slot, this does work newUTC.Insert(0,selectedItem);  newUTC is the source collection for a listcollectionview.  This just seems like overengineering of something that should already work out of the box.

Comment: I think, you should introduce a DTO  layer into your application to separate    entity data and ui logic. That would help you evade risks of occasional data change.